# MySQLi PHP Extension Problems

Tags: php, mysqli

Whenever a query finishes executing, I know you should free the result. Here is a snippet of a class I built for running a simple query. Could someone tell me where I went wrong? The query, when entered properly, runs successfully. It's just that my page doesn't reload like it, should but it gives me these errors...

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function free() on a non-object in <file> on <line>
```

... and this error ...

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function close() on a non-object in <file> on <line>
```

Here a simplified version of my code:

```
public function query($query) {
  try {
    if ($result = $this->connection->query($query, MYSQLI_USE_RESULT)) {
      $result->free();  //Problems here
      $result->close(); //Problems here
                
      return $result;
    } else {
      $result->free();  //Problems here
      $result->close(); //Problems here
      
      throw new Exception("The query was invalid");
    }
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mysqli\_fetch\_assoc() expects parameter / Call to a member function bind\_param() errors. How to get the actual mysql error and fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662488/mysqli-fetch-assoc-expects-parameter-call-to-a-member-function-bind-param)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I follow your link to the manual, there is something mentioned about the return value

> Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a result object. For other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.

Especially you don't handle the two cases `true` and more important `false`

```
if ($result = $this->connection->query($query, MYSQLI_USE_RESULT)) {
  $result->free();  // Probably call "free()" on true
  $result->close();

  return $result;
} else {  // <-- false, null, 0 or ""
  $result->free();  // Probably call "free()" on false
  $result->close();

  throw new Exception("The query was invalid");
}
```

I don't know, what `$query` is in your case, but `query()` will only return a result, *if* there is one (`SELECT`-query).

Comment: Of course. As I suggest only `SELECT`-queries has results. Everything else only return "success" (`true`) or "failure" (`false`). Even worse you test, if the result evaluates to `false` (the `else`-branch), but you call `free()` on it anyway.

Comment: After looking at your description again, yeah, that looks like you hit the nail on the head. That being said, is there a way I can see if this is an object?

Comment: `is_object()`, or just test against the booleans `=== true`, or `=== false`

Comment: I'm asking too many questions. :( `is_object()` will tell me if I have an object. Thanks for your help, KingCrunch!